# jar file exported by Eclipse won't run on most recent version of java VM

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

When I run the file through command shell I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: packageCalculator/Calculator has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

When I run:
java - version

I get:
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode, sharing)

Does Eclipse use a java version greater than current VM?
Please help to solve the problem

Comment: Eclipse is shipped with an embedded Java 15 used to run Eclipse. Configure the Java JREs/JDK in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ you want to use in your projects. Eclipse does not use `javac`, but has its own incremental Java Compiler that compiles to the Java version you have configured in your project (_Project > Properties: Java Compiler_).

Comment: You can tell Eclipse exactly what version settings to use for the Project in the Project Properties - look at the Java Compiler page. Class file version 59 is Java 15, 52 is Java 8

Comment: Ok, I know how to setup eclipse with another JRE, but why the java VM I downloaded from Oracle is so obsolete?

Comment: The current Java from the Oracle download page [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) is actually Java 16 (Eclipse needs a patch to support 16, that page also has a Java 15 download)

Comment: but then i have to download the sdk and I have to give all sort of information about my business to oracle.

Comment: If you don't want to agree to the Oracle license you can use the [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/) versions - same code, different license, less frequent updates

Comment: ok, thx i downloaded and installed the oracle version of sdk 16 but I still see that java version is unchanged: from java configuration I see it's the most updated.

Comment: See my comment above. You might consider to ship your Java application with a Java JRE, e.g. from https://adoptopenjdk.net/ (using Java 9 or higher, you can create via `jlink` a JRE with a minimal system library containing only those modules that are required by your application).